# How to properly serialize an object whose model has a foreign key which also takes an ImageField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
# models.py

class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PostImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=unique_upload)
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my model set up for a basic scenario where a user can enter content or upload images as their posts.

I want to bundle my logic to handle creating a post with either `content` or `images` or both.

I first started playing around with `GenericViewSet` and `CreateViewSet` but was images was never being passed to my serializer.

```
# views.py

class CreatePostViewSet(generics.CreateAPIView /* viewsets.GenericViewSet */):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Post.objects.order_by('id')
    serializer_class = CreatePostSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        print(request.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        serializer.save(created_by=request.user)

        # post = serializer.instance
        # print(post)
        # for im in post.images.all():
        #     im.save(post=post)
        # print(post.images.all())

        return Response(data,
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=self.get_success_headers(serializer.data))

# serializers.py

class PostImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'image', 'post',)
        read_only_fields = ('post',)
        depth = 1

class CreatePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = PostImageSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'content', 'images',)
        read_only_fields = ('created_by',)
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # validated_data['images'] is always []
        print(validated_data)
        raise
```

`images` is always `[]` when I pass it to a serializer, but it does exist in `request.data['images']` as `[<TemporaryUploadedFile: 1 - 5H5hHgY.png (image/png)>, ...`

I was hoping to use ModelSerializer to help auto-resolve the ImageField.

```
# CreatePostSerializer serializers breaks down to

CreatePostSerializer():
    id = UUIDField(read_only=True)
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='post-detail')
    content = CharField(allow_blank=True, required=False, style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    images = PostImageSerializer(many=True, required=False):
        id = UUIDField(read_only=True)
        url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='postimage-detail')
        image = ImageField(max_length=100)
        post = NestedSerializer(read_only=True):

            id = UUIDField(read_only=True)
            content = CharField(allow_blank=True, required=False, style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
            created_by = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

Comment: pls correct the *indentation* in your code snippets

Comment: apart from that, can explian the logic of two models? (I think one model is enough to hold the content and image)

Comment: There are 2 models as I want to be able to have `n` images associated with a post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It think `request.data['images']` will need to be changed slightly because your `PostImageSerializer` will be expecting an object containing the "image" key, whereas you are passing the list of `TemporaryUploadedFile`.

Given `request.data['images']` you could do something like the following in your view before you pass the data to the serializer:

```
images_list: List[TemporaryUploadedFile] = request.data.pop("images") 
images = []
for image in images_list:
    images.append({
        "image": image,
    })
request.data["images"] = images
```

So we are transforming your list of `TemporaryUploadedFiles` into a list of objects with the image key.

:edit: So you don't want to transform your data at the view to be compatible with the serializer?  Then you can change the serializer to be compatible with the data, this involves customizing the `create` and `update` methods, I'm just going to show you how to override the `create` method for now.

```
class CreatePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.ImageField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'content', 'images',)
        read_only_fields = ('created_by',)
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        images = validated_data.pop("images")
        post = super().create(validated_data)
        for image in images:
            serializer = PostImageSerializer(data={"image": image, "post": post.pk}, context=self.context)
            serializer.is_valid()
            serializer.save()
        return post
```

So you don't want to override the data in the request and you don't want to customize the serializers create method?  Change how the serializer converts your initial data into validated data with the `validate` method (I think this works for nested serializers but its untested):

```
class CreatePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = PostImageSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'content', 'images',)
        read_only_fields = ('created_by',)
        depth = 1

    def validate(self, attrs):
        images_list = attrs.pop("images") 
        images = []
        for image in images_list:
            images.append({
                "image": image,
            })
        attrs["images"] = images
        return attrs
```

Comment: I will try this out

Comment: I posted my results in the answer [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52886068/1294405). Is there any way to improve it? It feels like I am fighting against Django rest. I want to keep the 2 models as-is. The only difference I want to change for Create method is to pass data related to both `Post` and `PostImage` to push content and images in a single call, then list, update, etc can just be done normally.

Comment: What can be done on the serializer end so I don't have to get `request.data['images']` formatted a certain way?

Comment: I've updated my answer so you don't need to modify the request data, this involves customizing the serializer's create and update methods.

Comment: And yet another approach that involves implementing `validate` method so it does the same transformation that the view was doing, but in the serializers `validate` method.

Comment: I really do appreciate the info and thanks a bunch. Is there a preference for one way or the other? I figure it will depend on my use case, but starting up it seems it is simply a matter of whatever works.

Comment: Ideally the serializers and their fields should accurately describe the format of the data coming in and going out so you can use rest framework libraries for generating documentation (OpenAPI schema) from serializers and their fields, however this usually involves a lot more work.

Comment: So I wanted to use the latter method using `validate(self, attrs)`. It is still the same issue. `request.data['images']` isn't in `attrs` at all.

view: `serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)`

Comment: After doing some testing manually. It needs to be transformed right away before going to the serializer. So, it seems my only option is to do this manipulation in the view or send the data "correctly". So, technically it can be done normally, but using Postman it submits it a certain way.

Comment: Also, if you happen to read this. Keep everything the same in `class CreatePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)` whenever I submit data `content` is always an array. `self.get_serializer(data=request.data)` never works, because `content` is expecting a string, but got an array. It seems odd how in viewset it gets resolved fine, but this way I have to unravel it manually i.e.) `self.get_serializer( data={'content': request.data['content']})`.What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to get it to work with @ARJMP's suggestion.

```
# views.py

class CreatePostViewSet(generics.CreateAPIView):
    # authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Post.objects.order_by('id')
    serializer_class = CreatePostSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        print(request.data)

        images = [{'image': i} for i in request.data.pop('images', [])]
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            data={'content': request.data['content'], 'images': images})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        post = serializer.save(created_by=request.user)
        # self.perform_create(serializer)
        data['post'] = serializer.data

        return Response(data,
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=self.get_success_headers(serializer.data))

# serializers.py

class CreatePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = PostImageSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'content', 'images',
                  'is_private', 'created_by',)
        read_only_fields = ('view_count', 'created',)
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        images = validated_data.pop('images', [])
        p = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for im in images:
            pi = PostImage.objects.create(image=im['image'], post=p)
        return p
```

My thing is this seems rather convoluted to get it to work. A lot of manipulating it myself. I was really hoping to leverage more of the "magic" stuff that gets done with `ModelSerializer` and `CreateAPIView`.

Are there better approaches to doing this?

Comment: I've extended my answer with two additional approaches, by either changing how the serializer creates the models, or by changing how the serializer validates incoming data.